# Display Enum description in Jqgrid instead of the Enum

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I have an Enum like this written in Java:

```
public enum Status
{
  ACTIVE("Active"), IN_ACTIVE("InActive");

  Status(String desc)
  {
    this.description = desc;
  }

  private String description;

  public String getDescription()
  {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String desc)
  {
    this.description = desc;
  }
}
```

This enum is a property in a jqGrid. But it always display the enum i.e. ACTIVE or IN_ACTIVE. I want the jqgrid to show Active and InActive.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the JavaScript code which define jqGrid. Do you use `formatter: 'select'` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select))? Could you provide the mapping between the status and status description inside of the server response? It will be helpful if you post at example of JSON/XML data which return the server (one row of data will be enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to achieve this. For example:

```
formatStatus: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject){
   if (cellvalue == "ACTIVE")
       return "Active";
   return "InActive";
}
```

Then make sure to use the formatter from your colmodel:

```
{name: 'status', formatter: formatStatus, ...},
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This will definitely work. But i don't want to be redefining the descriptions of the enum probably in a script file or jsp. Is there no way of calling getDescription() on the enum so as to get the description. The reason is that, if i need to make a change say Active to Activated, i will only make it in one place. Thanks

Comment: @Uchenna - Depending upon how your code is structured, you could write out the values to variables on the page and then use those variables within your formatter. For example: `return ActiveStatusValue;`

Comment: Ok. i think that is fine. Are there any other ways of achieving the same.Because i was thinking, if one can use a javabean property on a grid like user.username, why can't one do the same with enum. just a thought. thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like a good option, since this will create a second place on the code where the textual values will have to be tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Have a toString() implemented in your Enum as follows

```
public toString() {
    return description;
}
```

This will make sure that your json response has description instead of Enum name.

Comment: This approach would have been the best option. But the problem here is that  i use this same enum in html select. So on modify of a form, the select will render the description of the enum in place of the value attribute of the select option. So the decription gets submitted to the server instead of the enum. Hope you understand this.